# If $\textbf{C}$ is an abelian category,thenthe category of presheaves of abelian groups on $\textbf{C}$ is abelian.Is $\textbf{C}$ abelian necessary?

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory, abelian-categories

I am looking at an exercise which asks that, if, $\textbf{C}$ is abelian, then the category of presheaves of abelian groups on $\textbf{C}$ is abelian. The proof of this proceeds as you would expect, by tediously checking every property to hold in the presheaves category. But it seems to me you never have to use the abelian-ness of $\textbf{C}$, only the abelian ness of $\textbf{Ab}$. For instance, given natural transformations $\alpha$, $\beta$: F $\rightarrow$ G, we define an operation on them as $(\alpha + \beta)_X = \alpha_X + \beta_X$ where the operation on the right arises from the fact that $Ab$ is abelian. Similarly, throughout the proof you use the abelianness of $Ab$, and not $C$. Am I missing something, or do we not need $\textbf{C}$ to be abelian?

Comment: @asdq No, these are components of natural transformations between functors $\mathbf{C}\to \mathbf{Ab}$, so you use the enrichment in $\mathbf{Ab}$..

Comment: @asdq are you sure about this? $\alpha_X$ and $\beta_X$ are in $Mor(F(X), G(X))$ which is an abelian group since $Ab$ is an abelian category.

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I was thinking about functors with values in $\bf C$, not presheaves on $\bf C$. Of course Arnaud is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need $\mathbf{C}$ to be abelian. In fact the category $[\mathbf{C},\mathbf{A}]$ is abelian whenever $\mathbf{A}$ is abelian. This is true because abelian categories can be defined entirely in terms of limits and colimits, and the limits/colimits in $[\mathbf{C},\mathbf{A}]$ are constructed pointwisely, from limits/colimits in $\mathbf{A}$.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but weird, given that it's my HW assignment and they explicitly stated that $\textbf{C}$ is abelian. The presheafs functors are contravariant $\textbf{C} \rightarrow \textbf{Ab}$ (your notation seems to allow for covariant). Even if they are contravariant, the result should still hold right?

Comment: Switching covariant and contravariant functors is the same as switching $\mathbf{C}$ and $\mathbf{C}^{op}$, so it makes no differences.